# How to remove selected item in combobox with right click when dropdown is open?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox

How to remove selected item in `ComboBox` with right click, when dropdown is opened?

Problem is that when you use event `SelectedIndexChanged` it doesn't have `MouseEventArg` as parameter, that mean you can't define which mouse button is pressed.

On the other side, when you use event `MouseDown` it can't detect when `SelectedIndexChanged`. In only one case `MouseDown` work when you press `Button.Right` and it is when you click on the `ComboBox` which don't have opened dropdown menu (basically right click on `ComboBox`).

Do you have some advice?

What I've tried so far:

```
private void combobox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        MessageBox.Show("mouse up");
}

private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((cmbSearch.SelectedIndex) != (-1))
    {
        combobox1.Items.RemoveAt(cmbSearch.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove items from the ComboBox while it's displayed?  This seems like a bad idea from the start.

Comment: Can you write your use case? Like, user selects item, clicks here, clicks there, expected behavior, etc...  `fact that when you use event SelectedIndexChanged it don't have MouseEventArg` is normal. Because `SelectedIndexChanged` is event of combobox anf `MouseEventArg` is event of user activity

Comment: @T.S. i already told use case, i need to remove selected item when is clicked on them with right click if you have any suggestion how to do that please let me know ....

Comment: @tonni Please see my answer. hope that what you looking for, or do you want to remove your item from the list completely? this is why I asked to give step by step user actions. This is how you define requirements

Answer (score 1):

I've set comboBox with bunch of items and made it `drop down list`.

I've added handler to `MouseDown` event

```
private void comboBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        return;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

What this does, if any item selected, when you right click on the comboBox, it deselects selected item.

Now, how you handle this change in your `SelectedIndexChanged` is completely different item. Hope this answers your question.